# D3 radial bar chart adjust radius scaling

Tags: javascript, d3.js, math, data-visualization

If one examines this block:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/8d2112a115ad95f4a6848001389182fb

The gridlines are in increments of 20. However the radius of each gridline does not appear to be equal as it scales up:

[image]

I'm guessing there is some geometric justification for this, but that's not what I'm after for my chart. I only want aesthetics, I need the gridline circles to be equidistant from each other.

### Question

Using Bostock's radial scale script as seen in the above block, is there any way to adjust the scaling of the radii? I want the scaling to be equidistant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you need is to change this...

```
var y = d3.scaleRadial()
```

... for this:

```
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
```

Here is the bl.ocks with that change only: https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/0a0b22d15c4e715e4c748335e37330fb/1670bbcdfdcbed6b6a0ae2a56d5f153570d969d1

---

PS: There is indeed a geometrical explanation for this: a circle with radius `2r` has an area **four** times bigger than a circle with a radius `r`. That's why we **always** (at least in truthful charts) scale the circle's radius to the square root of the encoded datum. Well, you mentioned that *"I only want aesthetics"*. As a data visualisation specialist/enthusiast who happens to be a D3 programmer, not the other way around, I suggest you reconsider your approach and keep the radial scale. Charts that prioritise aesthetics over information are normally bad charts, and charts that impose aesthetics **ignoring** information are simply untruthful charts.